# error LNK2005 already defined - Compiler error when building after running

Tags: c++, linker-errors, lnk2005

I'm trying to follow [Riemer's DirectX with C++ tutorial](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/C++/Series1/).

I have made a few changes, for example here I have made my `InitializeDevice()` function in a separate file (`tdirect.cpp` / `tdirect.h`).

When I press F5 to compile and run, the program works perfectly. But when I make a change to a value (e.g. `0xff00ffff` to `0xff0000ff` - cyan to blue) *without* choosing the "Rebuild" option I get a stream of errors in my console which prevent me from compiling the program. This is pretty annoying as you can imagine. It's as if it's compiling `tdirect.cpp` twice.

Here's the source code of `tdirect.cpp`, `tdirect.h`, and the relevant part from `main.cpp` (`tdirect.h` is ***only*** included from `main.cpp`, and `basicvertex.h` is only included from `tdirect.cpp`)

**`tdirect.cpp`**:

```cpp
#include "tdirect.h"
#include "basicvertex.h"

IDirect3D9 *pD3D;
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS D3DParams; 

LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 InitializeDevice(HWND Wnd)
{
    pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    if (pD3D == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(Wnd, "DirectX is not installed.", "No DirectX!", MB_OK);
        return NULL;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&D3DParams, sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS));

    D3DParams.Windowed = TRUE;
    D3DParams.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    D3DParams.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;

    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice;
    if (FAILED(pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, Wnd, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &D3DParams, &pDevice)))
    {
        if (FAILED(pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_REF, Wnd, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &D3DParams, &pDevice)))
        {
            MessageBox(Wnd, "Failed to create reference device.", "No software device!", MB_OK);
        }
        else {
            MessageBox(Wnd, "Falling back to software mode.", "No hardware device!", MB_OK);
        }
    }

    return pDevice;
}

LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 vBuffer;
void Init(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice)
{
    BASICVERTEX Vertices[3];
    Vertices[0].x = 150;
    Vertices[0].y = 100;
    Vertices[0].weight = 1;
    Vertices[0].colour = 0xffff0000;

    Vertices[1].x = 350;
    Vertices[1].y = 100;
    Vertices[1].weight = 1;
    Vertices[1].colour = 0xff00ff00;

    Vertices[2].x = 250;
    Vertices[2].y = 300;
    Vertices[2].weight = 1;
    Vertices[2].colour = 0xff00ffff;

    if (FAILED(pDevice->CreateVertexBuffer(sizeof(BASICVERTEX)*3, 0, D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &vBuffer, NULL)))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to create vertex buffer", "Fail", MB_OK);
    }
    else {
        void* pVertices;
        if (FAILED(vBuffer->Lock(0, sizeof(BASICVERTEX)*3, (void**)&pVertices, 0)))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to lock vertex buffer", "Fail", MB_OK);
        }
        else {
            memcpy(pVertices, Vertices, sizeof(BASICVERTEX)*3);
            vBuffer->Unlock();
        }
    }
}

void DrawScene(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice)
{
    pDevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,0), 1.0f, 0);
    pDevice->BeginScene();

    pDevice->SetStreamSource(0, vBuffer, 0, sizeof(BASICVERTEX));
    pDevice->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE);
    pDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 1);

    pDevice->EndScene();
    pDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

**`tdirect.h`**:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
```

**`main.cpp` include part**:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

#include "dxheader.h"
#include "tdirect.cpp"
```

Compiler Errors:

```
1>Debug\tdirect.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "struct IDirect3DDevice9 * __cdecl InitializeDevice(struct HWND__ *)" (?InitializeDevice@@YAPAUIDirect3DDevice9@@PAUHWND__@@@Z) already defined in tdirect.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl Init(struct IDirect3DDevice9 *)" (?Init@@YAXPAUIDirect3DDevice9@@@Z) already defined in tdirect.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl DrawScene(struct IDirect3DDevice9 *)" (?DrawScene@@YAXPAUIDirect3DDevice9@@@Z) already defined in tdirect.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "struct IDirect3DVertexBuffer9 * vBuffer" (?vBuffer@@3PAUIDirect3DVertexBuffer9@@A) already defined in tdirect.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "struct _D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS_ D3DParams" (?D3DParams@@3U_D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS_@@A) already defined in tdirect.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "struct IDirect3D9 * pD3D" (?pD3D@@3PAUIDirect3D9@@A) already defined in tdirect.obj
1>C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DirectX\Debug\DXStuff.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't do this: #include "tdirect.cpp" in your main!

Comment: So you are saying that doing a full rebuild works and you get no linker errors or warnings?

Comment: Full rebuild works, yes, no linker errors. I get a warning about some already defined symbols that it's ignoring, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're including an implementation file from your main.cpp, so it's adding the functions in again.  You can't do this:

```
 #include "tdirect.cpp"
```

Instead you need to create a header file with the function prototypes so you can reference them...

Do you have these defined in your "tdirect.h" (this is what main.cpp should be including)?

```
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 InitializeDevice(HWND Wnd);
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks for this! I had this already, but they were commented out whilst I tried to find the problem (which, in fact, was just me forgetting to add a prototype for a function I added later)

I'm still getting "Debug\tdirect.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored" but it's actually compiling this time.